# My home made carousel works perfectly but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a very simple carousel in jQuery, it works perfectly fine with all browsers except IE, it gets stuck on the first `div`,

Heres my function :

```
var Tcar='';
function carrousel(sens,loop){
    var indice=0;

    $(".imgDiapo").each(function(){
        if($(this).css("display")=="block"){
            indice=$(this).index();
        }
    });

    if(sens=="next") {indice++; }
    else{indice --; }

    if(indice> $(".imgDiapo").length-1) {indice=0; }


    $(".imgDiapo").fadeOut(300);
    $(".imgDiapo:eq("+indice+")").fadeIn(300);

    $(".pDroite").fadeOut(0);
    $(".pDroite:eq("+indice+")").fadeIn(300);
    if(loop=="loop") Tcar=setTimeout( function(){carrousel(sens,loop)},3500);
}
```

And my jsfiddle for example : http://jsfiddle.net/jrMqR/
and the result online : http://lapasserelle-massage.fr/index.php

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  Is it in compatibility mode?

Comment: The "basic version." You mean, without updates?

Comment: Sorry for commenting without helping, but when I read the title I thought "Well of course, nothing works perfectly in IE" :P

Comment: Yeah, but it dont works too with IE8, my script is very simple, does not IE support :eq ?

Comment: Seems to work for me in IE9 (in both IE9 and IE8 modes).

Comment: Thanks..  Dont even know why it was not working

Comment: How can i mark this topic as resolved?